# How to make an animated transition between two pages?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am building a Windows 8.1 app and I wondering how to show an animated transition between two pages. Right now I am simply using the Navigate method to change page but there's no animated transition.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is how MyPage should look like:

```
<Page> 
    <Page.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Page.Transitions>
....
</Page>
```